# how to git add -up changes from only specific files

Tags: git

For adding changes to index from working directory, I use `git add -up`.

Now I want `git add -up` to only show changes from specific files. How to do that?

Or Rather ignore few specific files and show changes from all others?

Note: I dont want to add the specific files to `gitignore` list, I just want to ignore them certain times as they also contain settings for debugging which I dont want to commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a little slow, but you could use the `--interactive` add:

```
git add -i
```

And choose which file to add, and even which part of the file add.

Comment: this followed by 5 or p, followed by file number, followed by "enter"

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the file:

```
$ git add -up myfile
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
$ git add -up path/to/myfil*
```